# How does a container ~read~ the secrets stored in a (mounted) secret volume?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

This article talks about how to MOUNT the Secret Volume.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-secret

> Use a secret volume to supply sensitive information to the containers
>   in a container group. The secret volume stores your secrets in files
>   within the volume, accessible by the containers in the container
>   group. By storing secrets in a secret volume, you can avoid adding
>   sensitive data like SSH keys or database credentials to your
>   application code.

But it does not discuss how to read-out the secrets after it (the secret volume) is created.

The germane code from the article listed below.

```
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "secretvolume1",
        "secret": {
          "mysecret1": "TXkgZmlyc3Qgc2VjcmV0IEZPTwo=",
          "mysecret2": "TXkgc2Vjb25kIHNlY3JldCBCQVIK"
        }
      }
```

It looks like any of the containers can mount this special secret volume.

```
          "volumeMounts": [
            {
              "name": "secretvolume1",
              "mountPath": "/mnt/secrets"
            }
```

How does the (parent) container (of the secret volume via the volume-mount) read out the secrets?  The secrets are not supposed to be file-persisted.

Better stated, how does my *application code* retrieve the secret values?

This guy almost got me there, but didn't. :(  He reads out the secret using the command line.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/secret-volumes-with-demo-and-empty-volumes-in-azure-container-instances/

Comment: The secrets are stored as files in your container.
To retrieve them in your application code, you just need to read them as regular files.

Comment: Thanks Robbie.  It was so easy..it was hard..(if that makes any sense).  Yeah I see it now.  Thanks for feedback.

Comment: For future readers. (I think???)  ...  The NAME of the secret becomes the filename. (so in example "mysecret1" would be the name of one filename)  And the value of the secret becomes the contents of the simple file.  So "TXkgZmlyc3Qgc2VjcmV0IEZPTwo=" (without quotes) would be the value inside the simple file.   #soEasyItsHard

Answer (score 3):

Good call granadaCoder. Yes, the key of the secret, i.e. "mysecret1", "mysecret2", becomes the filename in the volumeMount path, i.e. "/mnt/secrets".
Notice that the values of the secret should be base64-encoded. Their decoded values become the content of the files.
In your case, you will find /mnt/secrets/mysecret1 with content "My first secret FOO", and /mnt/secrets/mysecret2 with content "My second secret BAR" in your container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Key-Per-File Configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#key-per-file-configuration-provider) to read the secrets mounted in the Azure Container App. Every file under the directory will have its filename as the key, and the file content as the value. The directory path to the files must be an absolute path.

Here is an example:

Program.cs - .NET 8

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string secretsPath = "/mnt/secrets";
builder.Configuration.AddKeyPerFile(secretsPath, optional: true);
```

Comment: (please) change your var(s) to explicit types and add "using" statements, and I'll mark this as helpful.  you have the link, but links disappear over time.  thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Here you go, hope it helps someone in the future as I was looking for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you (for the tweaks).  And this is a valuable answer.